# Moment.js constructor in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, momentjs

I'm having some troubles using moment.js in IE8.

The following code works on IE11, chrome, firefox:

[Moment.js in IE8](http://jsfiddle.net/X3x5m/6/)

But in IE8, the `data2` variable is no correct (somo properties are `NaN`) and `data3` is correct.

How can I use moment.js in IE8 without using `._d`?

Answer (score 0):

By "data", I think you mean "date".  This link might help:

[Moment.js transform to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987647/moment-js-transform-to-date-object)

But frankly, IE8 has some serious problems.  Which you may - or may not - be able to work around.

IMHO...