# AngularJS how to add days / months / years to a date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are using AngularJS to set filters. 
Basically we have a start date and end date and frequency. When the frequency is set to week, we simply want to add 1 week to the start date, when the frequency is set to daily, we want to add 1 day to the start date.

Basically something like :-

```
var date = new date();

date.addDays(2);
date.addMonths(2);
date.addYears(2);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with AngularJS but my favorite date library is http://momentjs.com/ . Using that, you should be able to add days very easily with the syntax: moment().add('days', 7);

Comment: this is a basic javscript date issue and not hard to research

Comment: Please [read the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for the Date object.

Comment: It maybe a duplication of a Javascript question, and i realise Angular is javascript,  but the question was directed at AngularJS in particular.  if there are any functions/methods available within the AngualrJS frame work  in which this can be accomplished easily

Comment: What makes you think Angular has anything to do with dates?

Comment: @kapa nothing at all, the question was merely inquiring if angualarJS has any inbuilt functions which handle this, as per the .net framework does. however, it seems that it does not. thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/) for all of your JS date related needs then you can do:

```
var date = moment();
date.add(2, 'days');
date.add(2, 'months');
date.add(2, 'years');

// or all of the above with:
date.add({years: 2, months: 2, days: 2});
```

And if you need a regular JS date object at the end, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987647/moment-js-transform-to-date-object)