# Date generated by moment.js having invalid property

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The below function gives me the next business date:

```
function nextBusinessDate() {

      var today = moment();
      var tomorrow = today.add(1, 'days');

      // if saturday
      if (tomorrow.day() === 6) {
        tomorrow = tomorrow.add(2, 'days');
      } else if (tomorrow.day() === 0) {
        tomorrow = tomorrow.add(1, 'days');
      }

      return new Date(tomorrow._d);
    }
```

The date that it returns looks something like this:

```
myDate = nextBusinessDate();

// This is what myDate looks like in developer console
myDate: Fri Jun 19 2015 07:24:40 GMT-0400 (EDT)
__proto__: Invalid Date
```

The issue I am facing is that this wont get stored in firebase (which uses mongo I believe)

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Also, looks like this is the right behaviour: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1015

Answer (score 1):

As in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744045/1167456 you should not be using the _d method as it is a private method in the API. There is already a built-in converter to javascript Date for moment objects: `.toDate()`

Your return line should look like this:

```
return tomorrow.toDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the private `d`. Try using `.toDate()`.