# How to create a Date that takes UTC offset into account?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I am trying to add my users timezone offset to my DB query, since the dates in my MongoDB database are saved in UTC by default. Basically, I'm trying to query by *the users* 'today'.

I have my users Timezone. For this example let's say it is 'America/New_York' which currently has a -04:00 offset.

In the backend I am making a query:

```
let presentHour  = new Date().getHours();    //current hour of the day
let presentDay   = new Date().getDate();     //current day of the month
let presentMonth = new Date().getMonth();    //current month of the year
let presentYear  = new Date().getFullYear(); //current Year

Mood.find({

userId: req.user._id, 

createdAt: {
  "$gte": new Date(presentYear, presentMonth, presentDay, presentHour, 0, 0, 0),
  "$lt": new Date(presentYear, presentMonth, presentDay+1, 23, 59, 59, 999)
  } ....
```

As you can notice, I am not accounting for the offset.

From moment.js I am getting the timezone offset value like this:

```
-04:00
```

What is the best way to account for this in my query?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Comment: Thank you but this didnt really help me that much.

Comment: Can you expand a little bit more as what specifically you need help with ? Adding offset to Mongo query is not going to work b/c America/NewYork has DST

Comment: Let's say that, the DST variations are taking care of. I would just like to adjust the query to account for the -04:00. Aka modify the presentHour variable to account for it.

Comment: I would a little hesitant to adjust `presentHour` directly by offset. May be you can take a step back and create a moment object with the users timezone and convert it to UTC for query. Something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/17995098/2683814

Comment: `new Date(presentYear, presentMonth, presentDay+1, 23, 59, 59, 999)` will create a date for (almost) midnight tomorrow night.