# momentJs add days returns moment object instead of date

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I want to add 7 days in the date using momentJs in angular project.

```
let nextRunAt = "2018-08-16T02:00:00.242Z";

let calculatedRunAt = moment(nextRunAt).add(7, 'days');
```

I am expecting to get the date after 7 days but instead I get moment object.

Like below
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js transform to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987647/moment-js-transform-to-date-object)

Answer (score 4):

The moment method returns a moment object, you have to convert it to date-

```
let calculatedRunAt = moment(nextRunAt, "DD-MM-YYYY").add(7, 'days').toDate();
```

Comment: thankyou for the answer.. Also is there a way that I can get the `calculatedRunAt` as the same format to `nextRunAt`... I have updated my question