# getting only the date as Tue Jan 01 2019 11:35:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and not the prototype

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.js and what i see is that as user selects a date we get 
moment as an object where we have _d and also a prototype along wit it .
Here is how it looks .

```
d: Tue Jan 01 2019 11:35:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Date()
getDate: ƒ getDate()
getDay: ƒ getDay()
getFullYear: ƒ getFullYear()
getHours: ƒ getHours()
getMilliseconds: ƒ getMilliseconds()
getMinutes: ƒ getMinutes()
getMonth: ƒ getMonth()
getSeconds: ƒ getSeconds()
getTime: ƒ getTime()
getTimezoneOffset: ƒ getTimezoneOffset()
getUTCDate: ƒ getUTCDate()
getUTCDay: ƒ getUTCDay()
getUTCFullYear: ƒ getUTCFullYear()
getUTCHou
```

I  need to send only the Tue Jan 01 2019 11:35:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) part in the url while calling to api .How do we achieve this ?My concern is how to get rid of everything else .

Comment: You can pass object values by dot method lets assume date object something like object.d

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment.js transform to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987647/moment-js-transform-to-date-object)