# Dates with incorrect format

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I want to convert this type of date `Thu Oct 31 2019 15:07:23 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)` to this `2019-10-08T15:07:38` and I'm using mommentjs to convert the date but when I try to implement the next code I only get this `2019-10-23T15:07:23-05:00`.

```
const newDate = moment.parseZone(result).format();
```

The variable `result` have this value `Thu Oct 31 2019 15:07:23 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)` and the result is this `2019-10-23T15:07:23-05:00`. It doesn't matter if I need to use another library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
const newDate = moment.parseZone(result).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
```

docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Just a question more, how can I set this in a variable type Date?. Moment is an string so I want to know how to make that.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987647/moment-js-transform-to-date-object