# moment().startOf('day')` shows as `Moment<2020-05-01T00:00:00+02:00>`

Tags: node.js, date, momentjs

Why `moment().startOf('day')` shows as `Moment<2020-05-01T00:00:00+02:00>`, in Nodejs ??

I want to show the date only, how to get the date only without `Moment` word and `< >` symbols.. !

Comment: Because you get a Moment object. If you want to display that in a particular date format, read [the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) on how to do that.

Comment: do you want the plain js `Date` of that certain moment?

Comment: How to get the date only, from this object?

Comment: @sandrooco , I need start and end of the day..

Comment: Well what does the documentation say? What have you tried? What specific output do you need (e.g. a string `"2020-05-01"`)?

Comment: BTW: I can really recommend the `date-fns` library. It's way smaller than moment and uses the plain `Date`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moment.js transform to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987647/moment-js-transform-to-date-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `startOf()` returns a moment object, what you're wanting to do is some kind of format of the output object.

```js
console.log(moment()
  .endOf('day')
  .toISOString()) // 2020-05-18T21:59:59.999Z
```

Comment: From the question, it seems like OP wants the string. But you're right, shouldn't assume

Comment: Read the comments. :)

Comment: In fact I needed endOf and startOf day in milliseconds or epoch format, made this solution `+moment().startOf('day')  ` But yes this solves the question I made, removes the `Moment< >` and gives the date only..