# Javascript- Convert Date to Moment

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I convert a Date to Moment in Javascript?

```
let testDate = new Date(2020, 05, 03, 1, 2);
```

trying the following is not working

```
toMoment(testDate)
```

What is the proper syntax?

Comment: Maybe this ? Moment.js is very good JS library : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744045/390462

Comment: If you need to have local date, then : https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/local/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following

```
var momentObj = moment(testDate);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
moment(testDate);
```

It's as simple as that.

For detailed Information checkout: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/

Comment: thank you, I was testing toMoment(), you're right, simple as that