# Instable execution in firestore query using node moment in cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, moment-timezone

The following code running OK in an function, but, strangely, in other function return error. Both functions using node 16 and run in the same project. Field in collection is timestamp.

```
...
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
...

var timeInit = moment.tz(new Date(), 'America/Sao_Paulo');
timeInit.startOf("day");

var timeEnd = moment.tz(await addDays (new Date(), 1), 'America/Sao_Paulo');
timeEnd.startOf("day");

const ref = db.collection("myCollection");
const snapshot = await ref.where('fieldtime', '>=', timeInit)
                          .where('fieldtime', '<', timeEnd)                   
                          .get();
```

Error: Argument "value" is not a valid FieldValue. Couldn't serialize object of type "Moment". Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the 'new' operator).
at Object.exports. [as isFieldValue] (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:89:23)
at CollectionReference.where (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1096:18)

Edit 1:
If I use .toDate(), as follow:

```
console.log("timeInit format ", timeInit.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'));
console.log("timeEnd format ", timeEnd.format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'));

console.log("timeInit todate ", timeInit.toDate());
console.log("timeEnd todate ", timeEnd.toDate());
```

Console:

```
timeInit format 10-01-2022 00:00:00
timeEnd format 11-01-2022 00:00:00
timeInit todate  2022-01-10T03:00:00.000Z
timeEnd todate 2022-01-11T03:00:00.000Z
```

I' not lost the UTC-3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is:

> Couldn't serialize object of type "Moment"

Firestore has its own internal `Timestamp` object for fields. When querying a `Timestamp` field, you can either specify a `Timestamp` as the value, or a `Date` object. But (as the error says) a `Moment` is neither a `Timestamp` or a `Date`, so it can't be used as the value for a query.

From this question it seems you'll want to call `toDate()` on the `Moment` object to get a `Date` back: [Moment.js transform to date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987647/moment-js-transform-to-date-object)

Comment: Frank, thanks for answers. But, I have a concern. Look edit 1 in question.

Comment: That looks correct to me at first glance: "10-01-2022 00:00:00" in 'America/Sao_Paulo' is "2022-01-10T03:00:00.000Z", right? If you want to filter on the exact date, you should send the values in UTC (`z`) timezone.

Comment: I made tests and u are correct. Thanks.

Comment: but, why run ok in one function and crash in another is a misterious.